# Counting number of occurrences in column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Example (column A is input, columns B and C are to be auto-generated):

```
|   A   |   B   |   C   |
+-------+-------+-------+
| Name  | Name  | Count |
+-------+-------+-------+
| Joe   | Joe   |     2 |
| Lisa  | Lisa  |     3 |
| Jenny | Jenny |     2 |
| Lisa  |       |       |
| Lisa  |       |       |
| Joe   |       |       |
| Jenny |       |       |
```

I know I can do this with the function below. However, I would like to do it with app scripts. I have tried nesting 2 for loops called (`i` & `j`). Where it started with `i` and `j` counts until it doesn't match `i`. Then j equals `i` so `i` just jumps to the new start point as to not double count and it kind of worked.

I kept having a problem where it would output a high number on the last 2 iterations or so... I don't think I saved the script after I could not get it to work. any thoughts or help would be appreciated.

The formula I would like to make a script:

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY(A1:A16&{"",""},"select Col1, count(Col2) where Col1 != '' group by Col1 label count(Col2) 'Count'",1))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

It will read column A with header and generate B and C with headers

```
function pv() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn());
  const vs=rg.getValues();
  let Obj={pA:[]};
  vs.forEach(function(r,i){
    if(!Obj.hasOwnProperty(r[0])) {
      Obj[r[0]]=1;
      Obj.pA.push(r[0]);
    }else{
      Obj[r[0]]+=1;
    }
  });
  let oA=[["Name","Count"]];
  Obj.pA.forEach(function(p) {
    oA.push([p,Obj[p]]);
  });
  sh.getRange(1,2,oA.length,2).setValues(oA);
}
```

This is a simple pivot table

Comment: Full disclosure: I´ve started to go through ALL your apps script related answers to improve my coding skills, because the way you deal with apps script is simply amazing! That being said, how can your code above be changed to NOT read and/or NOT generate headers? Thank you so much in advance for your response :)

Comment: Please ignore my question above, because I found out the answer. And in case somebody else might be interested in my "finding": all you have to do to NOT read the header is change the starting row in the const "rg".

Comment: There are several ways to eliminate the header.

Comment: Can you add one of them to your script, if possible? Thanks :)

Comment: I did.  I started on line two.

Comment: Just saw it. Thank you so much again :)

Comment: You can use `rg = getDataRange.getValues()` and `var [hA,...vs]=rg.getValues()` and you can shift() it off.