# How to use Google App Script to locate unique names and add up their valued numbers

Tags: google-apps-script

So I used an importGoogleCalendar code to pull my workers' names and hours from Google Calendar to Google Sheets. However, I pulled EVEYRTHING. The names are duplicated a numerous amount of times in multiple rows for each day with their corresponding hours. How can I get one unique name for each worker along with their added up hours for each time their name appears on the sheet to another sheet so that it looks cleaner and easier to look at?

Example: I would like

| Name | Hours |
| --- | --- |
| Sam | 5 |
| Sam | 7 |
| Bob | 3 |
| Sam | 5 |
| Sam | 7 |
| Bob | 6 |
| Joe | 4 |

To look like

| Name | Hours |
| --- | --- |
| Sam | 24 |
| Bob | 9 |
| Joe | 4 |

Here is the code:

```
function importGoogleCalendar() { 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendarId = sheet.getRange('B1').getValue().toString(); 
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);

// Set filters
  var startDate = sheet.getRange('B2').getValue();
  var endDate = sheet.getRange('B3').getValue();
  var searchText = '';

// Print header
  var header = [["Title", "Description", "Start", "End", "Duration"]];
  var range = sheet.getRange("A6:E6");
  range.setValues(header);
  range.setFontWeight("bold")

// Get events based on filters
  var events = (searchText == '') ? calendar.getEvents(startDate, endDate) : calendar.getEvents(startDate, endDate, {search: searchText});

// Display events 
  for (var i=0; i<events.length; i++) {
    var row = i+7;

    var details = [[events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getDescription(), events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getEndTime(), '']];

    range = sheet.getRange(row,1,1,5);
    range.setValues(details);

 // Format the Start and End columns
    var cell = sheet.getRange(row, 3);
    cell.setNumberFormat('mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm');
    cell = sheet.getRange(row, 4);
    cell.setNumberFormat('mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm');

 // Fill the Duration column
    cell = sheet.getRange(row, 5);
    cell.setFormula('=(HOUR(D' + row + ')+(MINUTE(D' +row+ ')/60))-(HOUR(C' +row+ ')+(MINUTE(C' +row+ ')/60))');
    cell.setNumberFormat('0.00');
  }
}
```

I am willing to make another function if need be

Thank You and Stay Safe

Comment: "_I coded something_" - Can you [edit] your question to show us the relevant code? Between pulling the data and writing it to the sheet is where the aggregation can take place - but without seeing how you are sourcing your data, it is hard to say. In other words, can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: Please also remember to take the [tour] and take a look at [ask] for more guidance.

Comment: What you want is generally called a [pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62254307/7215091)

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34678309/summing-a-2d-array-by-group

Answer (score 1):

I like the approach of using a pivot table (since they are perfect for handling such data). You get totals, and other features for free.

But if you *only* want to write summary data to your spreadsheet, you can use the following approach:

My starting point follows on from this line in your existing script:

```js
// Get events based on filters
var events = (searchText == '') ? calendar.getEvents(startDate, endDate) : calendar.getEvents(startDate, endDate, {search: searchText});
```

From there I pass your `events` array to a new function:

```js
function summarize(events) {
  var totalsByName = new Map();

  events.forEach((event) => {
    let name = event.getTitle();
    // duration in seconds (from milliseconds / 1000):
    let duration = Math.abs(event.getEndTime() - event.getStartTime()) / 1000.0;
    if (totalsByName.has(name)) {
      // increment the existing duration for this person:
      totalsByName.set(name, totalsByName.get(name) + duration);
    } else {
      // add the first entry for this person:
      totalsByName.set(name, duration);
    }
  } );
  
  // iterate over each entry in the map:
  for (let [name, duration] of totalsByName) {
    console.log(name + ' = ' + (duration / 3600.0));
  }

}
```

The function populates a `map` of results - one entry per person's name.

In my example, all I do is print the data to the console.

```js
console.log(name + ' = ' + (duration / 3600.0)); // convert seconds to hours
```

But you can instead adapt all your existing code to write this data to the spreadsheet instead, using my `name` and `duration` values.

You can apply additional logic to sort by names, if you wish, and round the numeric data to a preferred number of decimal places.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestion, but I have a question. When you said you included it after my events variable, did you mean like this:         

`var events = (searchText == '') ? calendar.getEvents(startDate, endDate) : calendar.getEvents(startDate, endDate, {search: searchText});

    function summarize(events){...}`
Because I included the code, however, my console is not showing any of the data you said it should be populating it with.

Comment: That is not quite what I meant, no. My new function `summarize(events)` needs to be added to your script after the end of your existing function - not placed inside it.  Then you need to add one new line inside your existing function - a line which calls my function.  That new line is simply `summarize(events);` - and it is placed immediately after your `var events = ...` line. Sorry if that was not clear - but that is what I was trying to say when I wrote "_from there I pass your `events` array to a new function_". Let me know if that helps - or not.

Comment: Ok that makes more sense and is working now. Thank you so much!